# how to get computer IP that connect to my Pocket-PC?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

How can I get the IP of a computer that connects to my Pocket-PC ?

I need to see this IP in my Pocket-PC.

I work on VS2008 C# Windows-mobile

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ActiveSync connection itself is an RNDIS network, so the device and the PC have their own addresses in that network.  You can resolve "ppp-peer" to get the address of the PC in *that* network, but it won't tell you anything about the other network connection(s) of the PC.

To get that information, you would have to put an app on the PC that the device would talk to, and that app would provide the info you're after.